# Deployment of a Web Application made using vue framework

Tags: vue.js, deployment, web-applications, vuex

Everyone, I made a web application using Vue framework and it says to get a dist file before deployment which is done using :

```
npm run build
```

After building the dist file I put the whole application folder in my FileZilla. Now when I try to open the website it shows just the blank page. Does anyone know if I am missing any steps in Vue framework?

Comment: What web-server are you using ?

Comment: Have you read the Vue Deployment guide? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

Comment: Look at the console. Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

According to your server, and if you are using "history mode" of vue-router you have to do a specific configuration.
For example on appache server

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

More configuration : https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: I think that is not the only problem because if I remove mode:'history' it still won't work. There gotta be some way to deploy web applications. Everywhere I try to see they deploy it in Heroku/Github/Nginx. But I already hosted a website so I have no clue how I can deploy my web applications that uses nodejs/npm/frameworks.